# Rails presence validation is tricked by placeholder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, placeholder

On Rails 3.2.14, I'm having an issue with using placeholders in forms.

I have a presence validation in my model:

```
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

I have a placeholder in my form:

```
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Full Name" %>
```

If the placeholder isn't changed, rails seems to assume that the "Full Name" text is valid and present... therefore bypassing the presence validation.  The form is submitted with "Full Name" as the text for that field.

Is there a correct "rails way" to address this?

Comment: `placeholder: "Full Name"` should just add `placeholder="Full Name"` to the `<input>` in the HTML and that shouldn't affect the `<input>`s value at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured too.  Here is the source output: <input class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user[name]" placeholder="Full Name" size="30" type="text" />

Comment: Have you checked `params`? Have you removed the placeholder to see if that changes things?

Comment: Removing the placeholder does fix the validation issue.  Rails sees it's blank, and gives the validation error.  So somehow the placeholder is making it way as the :name parameter.  I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing this.  For a temporary fix, I just added labels to each field and removed the placeholder.  Placeholders are not supposed to be submitted with the form with HTML5, but Chrome version 30 and IE10 are both doing it.

Comment: Really? That's insane. Are you sure you don't have some sort of broken portability plugin making a mess of things?